# Свойство background-color разъезжается

Tags: html, css

Хочу придать тексту окраску. Вот стиль.

```
        <style>
            body{
                background-color:rgb(54, 54, 54);
            }
            p {
                background-color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
                font-family:monospace;
                color: rgb(19, 230, 11); /* Цвет текста */
            }

        </style>
```

Но задний фон текста почему то `разъезжается` на всю длину полей.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так понимаю, что необходимо применить фон непосредственно под текстом, а не на всю ширину строки. У вас это не получается, потому как тег `<p>` является блочным элементом, а значит растягивается на всю ширину. Как вариант для нужного вам параграфа применить свойство `display` и значение ему `inline`. Вот пример:

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(54, 54, 54);
}

p.demo {
  display: inline;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-family: monospace;
  color: rgb(19, 230, 11);
}
```

```html
<p class="demo">Ted</p>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, теперь понял =)